# R Function involving two for loops - baseball data

Tags: r, for-loop

For those into sports, I am working on a function that adds a column with the pitch count for a game in a given season for a pitcher.

For example's sake, data used is a data frame called pitcher that contains a game_date and sv_id (date/timestamp or the pitch). My goal is to order the sv_id in ascending order for each unique game_date and then add a column with a numbering system for this order. So for example, if for game_date=9/9/2018 there were 3 pitches thrown with sv_id's equal to 090918_031456, 090918_031613, and 090918_031534, I would first want to sort this data into chronological order (090918_031456,090918_031534,090918_031613) and then have a new column with the values 1,2,3 respectively to act as a pitch count. Below is my function so far. I originally thought I would make a list of lists but now I am not sure that is the right way to go about this. Please help! This is also my first time posting on here so any advice is appreciated. Thank you!!!

```
 `     pitchCount <- function(game_date, sv_id){
       gameUnique<-unique(pitcher$game_date)
       PC<-list()
       for (j in 1:length(gameUnique)){
         PCLocal<-filter(pitcher,game_date==gameUnique[j])
         PCLocal[order(PCLocal$sv_id),]
         for (i in 1:length(PCLocal$sv_id)){
         PCLocal$PC[i]=i
        }
       PC[j]=PCLocal$PC
       }
      return(PC)
      }

      pitch.Count <- pitchCount(pitcher$game_date,pitcher$sv_id)
      pitcher$PC<-pitch.Count
 `
```

Comment: I responded with an answer, but you should post a sample data set with your questions and desired output rather than just describing those things.

Comment: To piggyback on @hmhensen comment, it is generally best to post questions as an [mcve]

Comment: I will try that next time. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to count pitches as they come in order, right? Should be no need for a loop. In R, loops are rarely needed.

Check if this is what you want. A `tidyverse`/`dplyr` solution.

The `sv_id` variable is in a format that can be converted to `POSIX` (a type of date format). This makes it simple to sort in order.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create data_frame
pitcher <- data_frame(game_date = as.Date(c("2018-09-09", "2018-09-09", "2018-09-09")),
           sv_id = c("090918_031456", "090918_031613", "090918_031534"))

# First, convert sv_id strings to POSIX format (this can be done in the code below but this makes it clearer.
pitcher$sv_id <- as.POSIXct(c("090918_031456", "090918_031613", "090918_031534"), format = "%y%m%d_%H%M%S", tz = "GMT")

# Create pitch count
pitcher %>% 
  arrange(sv_id) %>% 
  mutate(Count = 1, pitchcount = cumsum(Count), Count = NULL)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  game_date  sv_id               pitchcount
  <date>     <dttm>                   <dbl>
1 2018-09-09 2009-09-18 03:14:56          1
2 2018-09-09 2009-09-18 03:15:34          2
3 2018-09-09 2009-09-18 03:16:13          3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! What else is this tidyverse package capable of?

Comment: @rcpulfer No problem. `tidyverse` can do just about anything. It's the dominant package in R. Some, like Peter below, prefer `data.table`. I'd suggest becoming more comfortable in `base` R and then learning `tidyverse`. `POSIX` is a `base` function after all. My answer could be actually done in `base`. It would just take a bit more space.

Answer (score 0):

Try using data.table.

```
library(data.table)

pitcher_dt <- data.table(pitcher)

> pitcher_dt
    game_date         sv_id
1: 2018-01-02 090918_031456
2: 2018-01-02 090918_031613
3: 2018-01-02 090918_031534
```

We can add Count column by := and add a position of 'sv_id' by order(sv_id).

```
pitcher_dt [, Count := order(sv_id)]

> pitcher_dt
    game_date         sv_id Count
1: 2018-01-02 090918_031456     1
2: 2018-01-02 090918_031613     3
3: 2018-01-02 090918_031534     2
```

Since Count only puts the position of 'sv_id', in this case (1,3,2), we can either sort 'Count' or 'sv_id' in ascending order

```
pitcher_dt[,order(Count)] or pitcher_dt[,order(sv_id)]

> pitcher_dt[order(Count)]
    game_date         sv_id Count
1: 2018-01-02 090918_031456  1
2: 2018-01-02 090918_031534  2
3: 2018-01-02 090918_031613  3
```

For me, it is easy to manipulate data with data.table. But, you can also use dplyr.
[Introduction to data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) is a good start to learn about data.table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is your data looks like, but I assume the following from your description

```
> df
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  game_date  sv_id        
  <date>     <chr>        
1 2018-09-09 090918_031456
2 2018-09-09 090918_031613
3 2018-09-09 090918_031534
4 2018-05-17 090918_031156
5 2018-05-17 090918_031213
6 2018-06-30 090918_031177
7 2018-06-30 090918_031211
8 2018-06-30 090918_031144
9 2018-06-30 090918_031203
```

Then you use `dplyr` to do generate your target

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(game_date) %>% 
    mutate(count = n_distinct(sv_id)) %>% #count sv_id with each game_date
    arrange(desc(sv_id))
```

The output is:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   game_date [3]
  game_date  sv_id         count
  <date>     <chr>         <int>
1 2018-06-30 090918_031144     4
2 2018-05-17 090918_031156     2
3 2018-06-30 090918_031177     4
4 2018-06-30 090918_031203     4
5 2018-06-30 090918_031211     4
6 2018-05-17 090918_031213     2
7 2018-09-09 090918_031456     3
8 2018-09-09 090918_031534     3
9 2018-09-09 090918_031613     3
```

I hope this could help

Comment: How do I take this count and add it to my original data frame?>

Comment: @rcpulfer, using `mutate` I added the count column to the output above that you can assign it to a variable (or your original data frame) instead of displaying it in console directly. I updated my answer above as an example.